# Determinant of almost skew symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant

Recently I was simply playing around with matrices and I discovered this:
If a matrix is skew symmetric except for its middle element then it's determinant is equal to the negative of the product of elements in the non principal diagonal.

For example:
[image]

This doesn't work with any other matrix with zeroes in the corners. Can someone explain how this happens?

Ps: I've tested it only for 3×3 matrices.